# "Bad number of pixels" type error when rotating skymap using healpy.rotator.Rotator.rotate_map

Tags: python, python-3.x, healpy

I'm trying to rotate a skymap in python 3 using the rotate_skymap function in healpy as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
from astropy.utils.data import download_file
from astropy. io import fits

def sin(x):
    return np.sin(x)

def cos(x):
    return np.cos(x)

theta_deg = 35 #degrees 

phi = 0
theta = np.radians(theta_deg) 
psi = 0

a11 = (cos(psi)*cos(theta)) - (cos(theta)*sin(phi)*sin(psi))
a12  = (cos(psi)*sin(phi)) + (cos(theta)*cos(phi)*sin(psi))
a13  = sin(psi)*sin(theta)
a21  = (-sin(psi)*cos(phi)) - (cos(theta)*sin(phi)*cos(psi))
a22  = (-sin(psi)*sin(phi)) + (cos(theta)*cos(phi)*cos(psi))
a23 = cos(psi)*sin(theta)
a31 = sin(theta)*sin(phi)
a32 =   -sin(theta)*cos(phi)
a33 = cos(theta)

euler_list = [a11, a12, a13, a21, a22, a23, a31, a32, a33]
euler_array = np.asarray(euler_list)
euler_deg = np.degrees(euler_array)
euler = euler_deg.reshape((3,3))

url  = ('https://dcc.ligo.org/public/0145/T1700453/001/LALInference_v1.fits.gz')
filename = download_file(url, cache=True)

r = hp.rotator.Rotator(euler, deg = False, eulertype = 'ZXZ')

R = hp.rotator.Rotator.rotate_map(filename, euler) #doesn't like this line
```

When I run the code though I get this error:

```
TypeError: bad number of pixels
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: I can't install healpy 1.12 right now to test this, but your file has four different columns. Can you try to rotate one at a time? `bad number of pixels` usually means that the input map is not a valid healpix array, i.e. one-dimensional array with a valid number of pixels.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks. I'll have a go at splitting it into arrays